# Experiencing total system freeze on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: kernel, filesystem, ssd, 19.10, nvme

It has been a while that I am experiencing some sever random system freeze with my new laptop with Ubuntu 19.04 as well as 19.10. I suspected that something might be wrong with the hardware as the whole system stops functioning all of a sudden and sometimes on the next boot it cannot load the OS due to some bad filesystem.

I am attaching the [varlog](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4cJwbk5FkD/) but I have a hard time figuring out what I need to do. Among the error messages these are noteworthy:

```
- Feb 03 10:35:37 nolitebook kernel: EXT4-fs error: 57 callbacks suppressed
- Feb 03 10:35:37 nolitebook kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4) in ext4_free_inode:355: Corrupt filesystem
- Feb 03 10:39:09 nolitebook kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000000
- Feb 03 09:54:39 nolitebook kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): __ext4_new_inode:1118: comm ThreadPoolForeg: fail
- Feb 03 09:54:42 nolitebook kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4) in ext4_free_inode:355: Corrupt filesystem
- Feb 03 09:54:01 nolitebook kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

I am suspicious of some hardware issues, possibly originating from a power issue with the SSD, as there seem to be some issues with SSD NVMe that has been discussed on some threads on the internet. But now looking at these errors, some of them succeeded a failure in the gnome-shell and I was wondering maybe some application is causing corruption in the filesystem and consequently fatal crash of the whole system. Also, to note that the SSD was upgraded from the default one.

I appreciate any insight or help with this.

> Update:
>   Some information about my NVMe SSD:

```
$ nvme list

Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     2J2920164244         ADATA SX6000PNP                          1           1.02  TB /   1.02  TB    512   B +  0 B   V9001b31
```

```
$ nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1

Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0n1 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 35 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 32%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 4,210,681
data_units_written                  : 4,391,468
host_read_commands                  : 53,652,657
host_write_commands                 : 57,846,680
controller_busy_time                : 0
power_cycles                        : 1,408
power_on_hours                      : 1,436
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 54
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 0
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0
```

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I am suspicious of some power issues with SSD NVMe and found this post that I am going to try suggestions from there and see if any of them helps. If you had any better in the meantime let me know. https://odd.blog/2013/11/26/yes-finally-fixed-ssd-freezing-computer

PS: my laptop is HP Elitebook 840 G5

Answer (score 0):

Repair your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p4`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: This would fix the issue temporarily but does not address the main problem that causes the corrupted file system. There is something that causes such corruption. I am suspicious of some power issues with the NVMe!

Comment: One step at a time. Do you have Windows installed? Have you checked for newer firmware for the NVMe? What make/model NVMe? What's the current firmware?

Comment: @NovinShahroudi status please...

Comment: I added some info about my NVMe. No, I do not have windows. And unfortunately could not find any firmware update for the NVMe that I could install via Ubuntu. Seems I need Windows for any kind of update on the HP Notebooks.

Comment: @NovinShahroudi Let's check syslog for error messages... do `grep -i ncq /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i fpdma /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i nvme0n1p4 /var/log/syslog*`. If they give lots of output, paste it at paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL.

Comment: @NovinShahroudi does your CPU or SSD temp ever get 70C or over?

Comment: Regarding the temperature, I often have my laptop being docked so not sure, but can track it. It is possible that it gets to 70C but doubt it since I did not see any log regarding overheating in the previous logs I had posted!

Comment: First command output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mfsw8Vv24X/ ---
Second command output: none ---
Third command output: /var/log/syslog:Feb 17 09:36:31 nolitebook fstrim[29802]: /home: 574.2 GiB (616539561984 bytes) trimmed on /dev/nvme0n1p4

Comment: @NovinShahroudi I just reviewed your syslog, and the inode corruption just gets worse as time goes on. I did notice CPU temps in the 71C range. Install the `Vitals` GNOME Shell extension and monitor the temps. What is `slack`? I checked the Adata site, and they don't say what the current firmware version is... only a Windows utility to check the firmware version, and I know that you don't have Windows. Since this is a new laptop... did it come with the Adata SSD, or did you upgrade to that later? How old is the laptop? Let's check your BIOS with...

Comment: @NovinShahroudi `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site and see if there's a newer BIOS available. Report back.

Comment: @NovinShahroudi the third command output doesn't look correct... let's try `grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*` instead.

Comment: Installed Vitals and monitoring the temperature now to see if there is any correlation between the freezing issue and temperature or not.

Slack the messaging app: slack.com

The laptop is pretty new.

I upgraded the SSD to Adata 1TB form the default SSD which was 256 GB (don't recall what was the default one specs!)...

Comment: ..I tried to update the BIOS before startup through LAN and seems to be updated. 

The version of the BIOS checked with the command you sent me is:
```Q78 Ver. 01.06.00```

Checking on the manufacturer's website from the link below seems the first part (```Q78```) matches but the revision does not ```01.09.01```: https://support.hp.com/ro-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-840-g5-notebook-pc/18491271

Also the output from the other command for the syslog is available here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4VCRFvXbpr/

Comment: **Noteworthy**: since the last time that I updated the BIOS I haven't experienced a universal system freeze but some temporary freezes occurred for a few seconds only on some applications like ```google-chrome```. I am going to put the laptop under more stress and report back!

Comment: @NovinShahroudi It wasn't clear... did you install BIOS 01.09.01? I don't know if you can do that directly from the current BIOS, or if Windows is the only way. I looked at your syslog post. There's a timeout that suggests that a SSD firmware update might really be in order. You may have to temporarily install Windows to install the BIOS update and check the SSD firmware. Show me `free -h`.

Comment: I have the BIOS ```Q78 ver. 01.06.00``` which I had updated through BIOS itself.
```free -h ``` shows: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d3TvwwZKnb/

Not really a fan of installing Windows now, but I can give it a try as a final resort.

Comment: @NovinShahroudi Go ahead and install the newer BIOS. Also, your swap is excessive. Show me `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`.